Did addiction rates and overdose rates skyrocket more in Oregon than in the rest of the US?
I read on Oregon recriminalises drug possession after overdoses rocket that:

The law rolls back an experimental policy [Measure 110] - the most liberal drug measure in the US - that made possession for personal use a ticketed offence with a fine up to $100 (£76).
[...]
Portland Mayor Ted Wheeler told the New York Times: "The truth is that addiction rates and overdose rates skyrocketed."

I wonder if addiction rates and overdose rates skyrocketed because of Measure 110 or because of nation-wide concurrent drug trends (e.g., fentanyl). Did addiction rates and overdose rates skyrocketed more in Oregon than in the rest of the US?

Addiction rates and overdose rates didn't skyrocket more in Oregon than in the rest of the US because of Measure 110, according the JAMA study {1}:

The findings of this study suggest that legal changes to remove or decrease criminal penalties for drug possession are not associated with the fatal drug overdose rate 1-year post implementation; further research is needed to examine the medium- and long-term consequences of these legal changes.


References:

{1} Joshi S, Rivera BD, Cerdá M, et al. One-Year Association of Drug Possession Law Change With Fatal Drug Overdose in Oregon and Washington. JAMA Psychiatry. 2023;80(12):1277–1283. doi:10.1001/jamapsychiatry.2023.3416


Ehm, in Washington the p-value was 0.06 https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/37755815/ rather close to being statistically significant.

Also "This study included data through March 2022, but provisional data from July 2022 to July 2023 demonstrates substantially larger increases in overdose deaths in Washington and Oregon compared with US other states." https://www.bu.edu/aodhealth/2024/02/27/policies-removing-or-reducing-criminal-penalties-for-drug-possession-in-two-us-states-not-associated-with-increased-rates-of-overdose-fatality/
